# Matlab: sort an array to ascending order in terms of binary interpretation

Tags: matlab, sorting, binary

The array contains binary numbers per line: one row means one binary number. They are in no order so I am trying to find a command by which I can sort them to ascending order, how to do it?

**Input**

```
>> [1 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 0 0; 1 0 1 0 0]

ans =

     1     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
```

**Goal:** by which command I can get by the input the below output?

```
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     1     1
     1     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: I don't have matlab handy to test it, but you should be able to do a radix sort using sortrows on columns n down to 1.

Comment: @beaker thank you, that worked nicely without any conversion in between -- could you copy my answer to your answer so mine could be deleted. +1

Comment: glad to have helped, but you should accept your own answer since it incorporates aspects from both my answer and Luis Mendo's.

Comment: @beaker ok, I upvoted the both answers -- it requires waiting 2 days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beaker answered in the comment *"you should be able to do a radix sort using sortrows on columns n down to 1."* -- and it works! Then Luis Mendo had a method to store the original positioning so putting the ideas together, vuola!

```
>> A=[1 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 0 0; 1 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 0 1]
[vv ii]=sortrows(A)

A =

     1     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1


vv =

     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     1     1
     1     0     1     0     0


ii =

     4
     2
     1
     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by converting to strings (`num2str`) and then from binary string to number (`bin2dec`):

```
[vv ii] = sort(bin2dec(num2str(data)));
data_sorted = data(ii,:);
```

Comment: As a side note, this is not going to work if too large data `Error using bin2dec (line 36)
Binary string must be 52 bits or
less.`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my suggestion in the comments, "you should be able to do a radix sort using sortrows on columns n down to 1.", the OP got the following code working:

```
>> A=[1 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 0 0; 1 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 0 1];sortrows(A)

ans =

      0     0     0     0     1
      0     0     1     0     0
      1     0     0     1     1
      1     0     1     0     0
```

And has now included Luis' cool idea for indexing.